# removing create new account tab from login page in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Drupal login page, while going from `url` `?q=user` shows you login form and it also shows `Change password` and `Create new account` tabs .
I want to remove the `Create new account` option/tab from there and also I do not want user to access registration page even via `url`: `?q=user/register`.

Anyone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To hide the `Create new account` tab in the `/user` path, you can insert the following in your module code:

```
function modulename_menu_alter(&$item) {
  // Hide the "Create new account" tab
  $item['user/register']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

This hides the tab but still allows for `/user/register` to be accessed.

Comment: Dear what if i want users to stop reaching registration form via /user/register?

Comment: @Mujtaba Mir - you can disable `/user/register` by `$item['user/register']['access callback'] = FALSE;`  Or if you have your own registration procees/form, you can use `$item['user/register']['page callback'] = 'your_function_here';`. This will replace the default behavior of visiting `/user/register`

Comment: For some tabs, it will be much easier to hide them with the Tab Tamer module - it can hide dynamic tabs generated by other modules (e.g. by the profile2 module).

Answer (score 10):

Open the `Configuration` admin menu, and under the `People` heading click `Account Settings`. Under the heading `Who can register accounts?` select `Administrators only` and then save the settings.

Comment: actually i want users to register themsedlves but not from the gate i mentioned above. i have an invite code on the front page, if user successfully submit that then i offering him registration form otherrwise sorry.. so thats why i wanna block user to register from other ways and also letting him register himself if have invite code.

Comment: That is at `admin/config/people/accounts`.

Answer (score 3):

The Tab Tamer module will do this. Just make sure you choose hidden and not disabled, otherwise users will get access denied errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Dee!
OP said "also need user cant access registeration page via url: ?q=user/register" and Tab hammer unfortunately can't do this when hidden.

Comment: The advantage of the Tab Tamer module is that it can hide dynamic tabs generated by other modules (e.g. by the profile2 module).

Answer (score 2):

Home>administration>configuration>people> who can register accounts> select administrators only

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "Register Tab" in login page for visitors, go to Administration>>Account Settings>> select the administrator to create the account. Save the changes. By doing this, only "Admin" can create the accounts. Users cannot see the "Register" Tab.

Comment: The OP posted in a comment above that he actually wanted to let users still create their own accounts, just not through the registration page. Setting the site to only allow admins to create accounts would stop him from accomplishing his goal.